# Storing a very large string array or string?

Tags: c#, winforms, string, visual-studio, memory

I have a large list of 1600 autocomplete options for my textbox in Visual Studio. What is the best way to add those options to the textbox custom autocomplete list?

I currently have all the settings in my text editor separated by semicolons. Should I just copy that into VS as a string as add it to the list by splitting it into an array with the semicolons as the delimiter? Would it be better to convert the code into a string array like: new string[x]{"setting1","setting2","setting3","setting4"}... etc? Should I store it in the application settings or in a new file and put it as a resource? Are all these essentially the same thing?

Comment: are you using asp.net or wpf/silverlight?

Comment: Winforms. I'll update the tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a list that large, my primary concern (other than speed) would primarily be maintainability.

If it were my application, I would store this in a file and either read that file in at app startup or store it as an embedded resource depending on the need to customize or update once deployed.

In fact, I would start with a standalone file until I understood the pace of change on the file, if any.

Comment: The list is static, so no need to change anything once implemented. Putting it straight into the code is fine then?

Comment: If this is not a frequent feature/page in your application, you could consider having it in a file/resource but when the application needs it, access it through a Cache so that memory usage will not be there in instances where feature not in use for some time. Anyway it'll be a balancing part of the solution.